# Custom Method Annotation using Jersey's AbstractHttpContextInjectable not Working

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, dropwizard

I want to restrict some methods if they are being accessed in a non-secure manner. I'm creating a @Secure annotation that checks whether or not the request was sent over secure channels. However, I cannot create a method injectable that captures the HttpContext of the request.

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Secure {

}

public class SecureProvider<T> implements InjectableProvider<Secure, AbstractResourceMethod> {
    @Override
    public ComponentScope getScope() {
        return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public Injectable<?> getInjectable(ComponentContext componentContext,
                                       Secure annotation,
                                       AbstractResourceMethod method) {
        return new SecureInjectable();
    }
}

public class SecureInjectable<T> extends AbstractHttpContextInjectable<T> {
    @Override
    public T getValue(HttpContext context) {    
        // validation here

        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm using the Dropwizard framework, so initialization of the Providers should be as easy as:

```
environment.addProvider(new SessionRestrictedToProvider<>(new SessionAuthenticator(), "MySession"));
environment.addProvider(new SecureProvider<>());
environment.setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());
```

Usage:

```
@Resource
@Path("/account")
public class AccountResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/test_secure")
    @Secure
    public Response isSecure() {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

At this point I'm assuming that a HttpContext Injectable doesn't work on a method, but I'm at a loss as to what other options I could utilize to implement this annotation.

Comment: From your example I don't really get the goal you are trying to achieve. Do you want to restrict access to some methods (urls) if they are being accessed in non-secure manner, or you would like to have injectable boolean value (to be provided as an argument to method) representing request type secure/non-secure?

Comment: I want to restrict some methods if they are being accessed in a non-secure manner. Sorry, I should have made that clearer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use AOP, I think you can do this by implementing ResourceMethodDispatchProvider and ResourceMethodDispatchAdapter.

```
public class CustomDispatchProvider implements ResourceMethodDispatchProvider {

ResourceMethodDispatchProvider provider;

CustomDispatchProvider(ResourceMethodDispatchProvider provider)
{
    this.provider = provider;
}

@Override
public RequestDispatcher create(AbstractResourceMethod abstractResourceMethod) {
    System.out.println("creating new dispatcher for " + abstractResourceMethod);

    RequestDispatcher defaultDispatcher = provider.create(abstractResourceMethod);
    if (abstractResourceMethod.getMethod().isAnnotationPresent(Secure.class))
        return new DispatcherDecorator(defaultDispatcher);
    else
        return defaultDispatcher;
}

@Provider
public static class CustomDispatchAdapter implements ResourceMethodDispatchAdapter
{

    @Override
    public ResourceMethodDispatchProvider adapt(ResourceMethodDispatchProvider provider) {
        return new CustomDispatchProvider(provider);
    }

}

public static class DispatcherDecorator implements RequestDispatcher
{
    private RequestDispatcher dispatcher;

    DispatcherDecorator(RequestDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    public void dispatch(Object resource, HttpContext context) {
        if (context.getRequest().isSecure())
        {
            System.out.println("secure request detected");
            this.dispatcher.dispatch(resource, context);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("request is NOT secure");
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot access this resource over an insecure connection");
        }

    }

}
}
```

In Dropwizard, add the provider like this:
    environment.addProvider(CustomDispatchAdapter.class);

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT** this works with JAX-RS 2.0. Though Jersey is now on version 2.4.1, Dropwizard is sadly still using 1.17.1 :(.

You could use a `ContainerRequestFilter` together with your annotation.

First, the annotation:

```
// need a name binding annotation
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Secure { }
```

Next, the filter:

```
// filter will only be run for methods that have @Secure annotation
@Secure
public class SecureFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        // check if HTTPS
        if (!requestContext.getSecurityContext().isSecure())
        {
            // if not, abort the request
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                                             .entity("HTTPS is required.")
                                             .build());
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly, registering the filter. This depends on how you set up your Jersey app. Here are two ways you might have set it up, but there are many other possibilities so I won't cover them all.

If you have a `ResourceConfig` with grizzly, you would want this:

```
final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
            .packages("my.package.for.resources")
            .register(SecureFilter.class);
```

If you're using the custom application model:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("my.package.for.resources");
        register(SecureFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Resource
@Path("/account")
public class AccountResource {

    // filter will run for this method
    @GET
    @Path("/test_secure")
    @Secure
    public Response isSecure() {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    // filter will NOT run for this method
    @GET
    @Path("/test_insecure")
    public Response allowInsecure() {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is solution for JAX-RS 2.0. Unfortunately, Dropwizard (latest release 0.6.2) still uses version 1.17.

Comment: Oh no! Sadly you are correct. I didn't check the Dropwizard docs and assumed they used JAX-RS 2.0. Well, I will leave this answer up in case someone comes across it looking for a 2.0 solution. Also, Dropwizard should really upgrade, the new spec is much easier to use.

Comment: Hmm, why is `SecureFilter` itself annotated with `@Secure`?

Comment: It's because @Secure annotation is marked as NameBinding (http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html) which binds resource methods to filters/interceptors.

Comment: It doesn't make sense as is.   That @Secure cannot be applied to the class because its target type is only METHOD.   Please edit to {ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.TYPE} or something alike...

Comment: Sadly I can't upvote because of the JAX-RS version mismatch, but this helped me with latest Jersey. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Allowing annotated methods to be accessed only via secure channel can be done using AOP. Please find the solution using Guice and it's AOP capabilities (of course other AOP solutions could be used).

You will need Guice library (com.google.inject:guice:3.0).

First of all create annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Secure {}
```

then configure guice bundle

```
public class SecurableMethodsService extends Service<Configuration> {

  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<Configuration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(GuiceBundle.newBuilder().addModule(new SecurableMethodsDemonstrationModule()).build());
  }

  @Override
  public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
  }

}
```

module binds method interceptor

```
public class SecurableMethodsDemonstrationModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(SecuredMethodsContainingResource.class);
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Secure.class), new OnlySecureAllowedInterceptor(getProvider(SecurityContext.class)));
  }

}
```

which checks if connection is secure (note: in this example resource is reported as not found if connection is not secure, you might need to adjust this for your use case)

```
public class OnlySecureAllowedInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  private final Provider<SecurityContext> securityContextProvider;

  public OnlySecureAllowedInterceptor(Provider<SecurityContext> securityContextProvider) {
    this.securityContextProvider = securityContextProvider;
  }

  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    if (!securityContextProvider.get().isSecure()) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    return invocation.proceed();
  }

}
```

and finally the resource with secured method looks like

```
@Path("")
public class SecuredMethodsContainingResource {

  @GET
  @Path("for-all")
  public String forAll() {
    return "for-all";
  }

  @GET
  @Path("secure")
  @Secure
  public String secure() {
    return "secure";
  }

}
```

Comment: I added dependency on dropwizard-guice instead (com.hubspot.dropwizard:dropwizard-guice:0.7.0.2) - GuiceBundle was not included in Guice library