# Spring RestEasy interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resteasy

I have a Spring boot application with resteasy-spring-3.0.19 and jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec-1.0.0.

I would like to intercept all the rest calls for authorization.

The interceptor is not getting invoked. Also, How can i get the target method @Path annotation value in the interceptor.

Do I need to register this in the Spring boot app?

```
@Provider
public class AuthorizationtInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter{

    /**
     * 
     */
    public AuthorizationtInterceptor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        String method = requestContext.getMethod();

        UriInfo uriInfo = requestContext.getUriInfo();

        // Need the target method @Path annotation value ....

    }

}
```

Target Rest class,

```
@Named
@Singleton
@Path(ROOT_PATH)
public class WebController {

    @GET
    @Path(TEST_PATH)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUser(@Context final HttpServletRequest request) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a post-matching filter (a filter without the [`@PreMatching`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/PreMatching.html) annotation), you can use [`ResourceInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) to get the matched resource class and the resource method.

Inject [`ResourceInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) in your filter using the [`@Context`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation:

```java
@Context
private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;
```

Then get the resource class and extract the [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation:

```java
Path path = resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(Path.class);
```

To get the resource method, use:

```java
Path path = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(Path.class);
```

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, instead of comparing the value of the [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation for authorization purposes, you could consider binding your filter to a set of resource classes or methods. See more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649605/1426227).

---

Depending on how you are setting up your application, you may need to register the filter in your [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) subclass or in your `web.xml` deployment descriptor.

Comment: It is getting invoked after registering the filter as if we register other filters in class with @Configuration annotation. Path path = resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(Path.class); returns class annotation, not the method that matches. I need the HttpServletRequest also, So I use Context 
    private HttpServletRequest request;. Is this ok?

Comment: @user1578872 Yes, you can inject the `HttpServletRequest` using `@Context HttpServletRequest request`. For a complete list of types that can be injected with `@Context`, refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35868654/1426227).